# How much potassium sorbate is needed to prevent yeast from multiplying?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, secondary-fermentation, additives, potassium-sorbate

I would like to ferment 2 and 4 Liters of papaya and watermelon (respectively) but am looking for how much potassium sorbate is needed, for each volume, to prevent yeast from multiplying.

An equation, for future reference would be nice but an exact answer is welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would depend on how much yeast was pitched, but the general consensus is that a 1/2 teaspoon per gallon of wine is enough to halt fermentation.
So for liters it would be a little more than an 1/8 teaspoon per liter.